# Recompiling PHP - relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1'

Tags: php

Im running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.
Openssl was installed via apt-get.

I have a problem with IMAP, so I was trying to recompile PHP in order to use the newly created IMAP.so module.

I use the following configure command on my php directory.

```
./configure --without-kerberos --with-imap=shared,/usr/imap-2007f --with-imap-ssl
```

This runs smoothly

When I try to make PHP. I get the following error.

```
/usr/imap-2007f/c-client -lc-client -lcrypt -lpam -lssl -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/imap-2007f/c-client/libc-client.a(osdep.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you might be mixing 32 and 64 bit architectures...

Comment: no distinction in the downloads available for either PHP or IMAP, so don't think so.

Comment: Found quite a few suggestions to re-install openssl using ./config enable-shared. But as am using apt-get how does one do that?